# All MP3 media from an array is not playing properly: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I have created an activity, in which different mp3 sounds have to be played onFling a TextView. I created an array with all media required. Sometimes this plays all the media properly but most of the time it stop playing in between.

```
private int[] voice ={R.raw.media1,R.raw.media2,R.raw.media3,R.raw.media4,R.raw.media5,R.raw.media6,R.raw.media7,R.raw.media8};

media = MediaPlayer.create(BaseActivity.this, voice[num]);
media.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating here as I have got the solution. I was facing such issues as I was not releasing the recourses. After using below code, issue resolved:

```
private int[] voice ={R.raw.media1,R.raw.media2,R.raw.media3,R.raw.media4,R.raw.media5,R.raw.media6,R.raw.media7,R.raw.media8};


if(media!=null){
    media.stop();
    media.release();
    media=null;
}
media = MediaPlayer.create(BaseActivity.this, voice[num]);
media.start();
```